# In javascript is it possible to partially import an "intermediate module"?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I created a Things folder that has many Thing files and then create an index inside the Thing folder that acts as an "intermediate module".

Like this...

```
// things/thing1.js
console.log('thing1 loaded');

const thing1 = () => {
  console.log('Hi from thing1!');
};

export default thing1;
```

```
// things/thing2.js
console.log('thing2 loaded');

const thing2 = () => {
  console.log('Hi from thing2!');
};

export default thing2;
```

```
// things/index.js
export { default as thing1 } from './thing1';
export { default as thing2 } from './thing2';
```

When I import any of the files from the intermediate module...

```
// anotherFile.js
import { thing1 } from '../things';

thing1();
```

...all the files are loaded.

```sh
# console output
thing1 loaded
thing2 loaded # <-- don't want this to load.
Hi from thing1!
```

Other than...

```
import thing1 from './things/thing1';
import thing2 from './things/thing2';
```

...is it possible to structure the intermediate module or the import so only the file being imported is loaded?

Comment: Use tree shaking to remove unused exports, check out webpack

Comment: That wouldn't really make sense; your `things/index.js` has to load all of its modules in order to export them. The only way would probably be to use some bundler to minimize your JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general way your current code is set up, no, it's not possible. Whenever a module is imported, *everything* it imports will also be imported (and their top-level code will run).

One options is to change the `thing1` and `thing2` modules so that they export *functions* which, when run, load themselves - that way, their initialization can be run on demand, rather than whenever they're imported (side-effects that result from just importing often isn't a good idea anyway - better if the entry point alone can control when things start running):

```
// things/initThing1.js
export default () => {
  console.log('thing1 loaded');

  const thing1 = () => {
    console.log('Hi from thing1!');
  };

  return thing1;
};
```

and

```
// anotherFile.js
import { initThing1 } from '../things';

const thing1 = initThing1();
thing1();
```

(or you could initialize in the intermediate module, if other modules import from `index.js`)